# InvalidAuthenticityToken in post_via_redirect

Tags: security, ruby-on-rails-3.2, csrf

We are migrating `Rails 3.0.0` to `Rails 3.2.21`. Suddenly we started experiencing `InvalidAuthenticityToken` in integration test where user is signing in(see below).

`post_via_redirect login_url, {:login => { :login => @user.login, :password => @user.password }`

We have custom authentication logic and it was working perfectly earlier.

We also tried passing `authenticity_token` manually in above call but it doesn't help. We tried to debug and found that when we pass `authenticity_token`(using `SecureRandom.base64(32)`) the `_csrf_token` value doesn't match with the one we pass in `authenticity_token`.

Are we missing any configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define one method for authenticity_token and use wherever you get this error.

```
def set_form_authenticity_token
    session[:_csrf_token] ||= SecureRandom.base64(32)
end
```

Ex. 
`params.merge(authenticity_token: set_form_authenticity_token)`